# How do i write down "unique representation" formally?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let me start my question with an example.

Suppose $\beta$ is a basis for a vector space $V$. Then, for every $v\in V$, if $v=\sum_{i\in I} a_i u_i$ and $v=\sum_{i\in I} b_i u_i$, then for all $i\in I, a_i=b_i$.($I$ is an indexing set for $\beta$) Hence, we can conclude that every vector in $V$ has a unique representation with respect to the basis $\beta$.

This argument seems very shaky to me. How do we write "unique representation" precisely in first-order logic? This seems quite intuitive to me, not abstract. Is there anyway to make "$\sum_{i\in I}$" the actual sum?

For instance, one can actually give a topology on  $R[[X]]$, hence make the formal sum the actual sum.

Just like formal sum, is there anyway to give a topology on a vector space $V$? If it is not worth doing this, then what would be the way to say "unique representation" in first-order logic?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I don’t see the problem: ‘if $\sum_{i\in I}a_iu_i=\sum_{i\in I}b_iu_i$, then $\forall i\in I(a_i=b_i)$’ says precisely that the representation, if it exists, is unique. (Existence requires a separate statement.) And these **are** actual sums.

Comment: @Brian Yes, only if $\sum_{i\in I}$ is well-defined. It is on wikipedia that one should not be confused that $\sum_{i\in I}$ is not a sum. What is the definition for $\sum_{i\in I}$?

Comment: How are they actual sums? Even though only finite terms are nonzero, it is an infinite sum. This is what i tried. "Define $\sum_{i\in I} a_i u_i$ to be $A$ if there exists a finite subset $F$ of $I$ such that for every finite subset of $G$, $F\subset G\subset I$ implies  $\sum_{i\in G} a_i u_i = A$." However, i cannot apply this for writing down "unique representation"

Comment: That depends on what’s inside the summation. In the vector space context, it’s just ordinary vector addition.

Comment: How is it **not** an actual sum if only finitely many terms are non-zero?!

Comment: @Brian Just like one cannot prove that infinite product of nonempty set is nonempty without choice principles, i think it should be defined even though only finite terms are nonzero. I feel very uncomfortable to say $\sum_{i\in I}$ is an actual sum..

Comment: I just don’t understand why you feel uncomfortable. (Of course I also take AC for granted whenever it’s useful, but I don’t see any real similarity between the two situations.)

Comment: How could one disprove or prove that $\sum_{i\in I} 0 ≠ 0$ unless infinite sum is defined..

Comment: It’s **defined** so that $\sum_{i\in I}0=0$: since you know that only finitely many terms are non-zero, you define it to be the sum of the non-zero terms, if there are any, and $0$ otherwise.

Comment: @Brian Finally i got it.. Thank you very much!

Comment: You’re welcome! Sorry if I sounded a bit short; I was really having trouble seeing where the problem was.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Please consider converting your comment(s) into an answer, so that this question gets removed from the [unanswered tab](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/3138). If you do so, it is helpful to post it to [this chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9141) to make people aware of it (and attract some upvotes). For further reading upon the issue of too many unanswered questions, see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/143113), [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1148) or [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9868).

Answer (score 1):

This is an attempt to summarize the discussion in the comments in order to get this off the Unanswered list.

Let $\beta=\{u_i:i\in I\}$. By definition we consider only sums $\sum_{i\in I}a_iu_i$ in which $\{i\in I:a_i\ne 0\}$ is finite. This ensures that $\sum_{i\in I}a_iu_i$ is well-defined: we define

$$\sum_{i\in I}a_iu_i=\begin{cases}
\sum\{a_iu_i:i\in I\text{ and }a_i\ne 0\},&\text{if }\{i\in I:a_i\ne 0\}\ne\varnothing\\\\
0,&\text{otherwise}\;,
\end{cases}$$

so it’s always either $0$ or a finite sum. Thus, it really is meaningful to say that

> $\qquad\qquad\qquad$if $v=\sum_{i\in I}a_iu_i$ and $v=\sum_{i\in I}b_iu_i$, then $a_i=b_i$ for all $i\in I$.

The actual proof involves a bit of bookkeeping. Let $I_a=\{i\in I:a_i\ne 0\}$ and $I_b=\{i\in I:b_i\ne 0\}$; $I_a\cup I_b$ is finite, and $a_i=b_i=0$ for $i\in I\setminus(I_a\cup I_b)$. For $i\in I_a\cup I_b$ let $c_i=a_i-b_i$, and let $c_i=0$ for $i\in I\setminus(I_a\cup I_b)$; then $\sum_{i\in I}c_iu_i=0$, so $c_i=0$ for all $i\in I$, and in particular $a_i=b_i$ for all $i\in I_a\cup I_b$ and hence for all $i\in I$.